# 'require': no such file to load (LoadError): when running foreman

Tags: ruby, rubygems, foreman

I've got a foreman Procfile that runs a ruby script:

`concat: ruby bin/compile_scripts_for_dev_automatically.rb`

When I run the script, I get the following error:

`bin/compile_scripts_for_dev_automatically.rb:10:in 'require': no such file to load -- listen (LoadError)`

I'm requiring 'listen' with `require 'listen'`

I've checked that I only have one copy of ruby on my computer:

```
$ which -a ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

And when I try to require `listen` in IRB, it works:

```
$ irb
>> require 'listen'
=> true
```

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: try `require './listen'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things I tried worked.

I could either add this to the top of my script:

```
require 'rubygems'
```

Or I could run the script as follows:

```
ruby -rubygems myscript.rb
```

I went with the latter because of this post https://gist.github.com/rtomayko/54177 that recommends not requiring rubygems in your scripts, as they force the user to use rubygems to manage gems.